# Highest Record for a set user

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hope someone can help.
I have been trying a few queries but I do not seem to be getting the desired result.

I need to identify the highest ‘’claimed’’ users within my table without discarding the columns from the final report.

The user can have more than one record in the table, however the data will be completely different as only the user will match.

The below query only provides me the count per user without giving me the details.

```
  SELECT User, count (*) total_record
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY User
  ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

Table:

```
 mytable
 Column 1 = User Column 2 = Ref Number Column 3 = Date
```

The first column will be the unique identifier, however the data in the other columns will differ, therefore it needs to descend the highest claimed user with all the relevant rows to the user to the least claimed user.

```
User|Ref Num|Date   
1|a|20150317
1|b|20150317
2|c|20150317
3|d|20150317
4|e|20150317
1|f|20150317
4|e|20150317
```

The below data is how the values should be returned.

```
User|Ref Num|Date|Count 
1|a|20150317|3
1|b|20150317|3
1|f|20150317|3
2|c|20150317|1
3|d|20150317|1
4|e|20150317|2
4|e|20150317|2
```

Hope it makes sense.

Thank you

Comment: What type of database are you using? (MSSQL, MySQL, etc)

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio? Does that help? Sorry very new to SQL

Comment: It's ok! As your using MSSQL you're able to use a window function, see my answer for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's input. I am currently busy testing all the suggestions, as it is also a good learning curve for me. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using MSSQL you can use the `OVER()` clause like so:

```
SELECT  [user], mt.ref_num, mt.[date], COUNT(mt.[user]) OVER(PARTITION BY mt.[user])
FROM    myTable mt
```

More about the `OVER` clause can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

As per your comment you can use the wildcard `*` like so:

```
SELECT  mt.*, COUNT(mt.[user]) OVER(PARTITION BY mt.[user])
FROM    myTable mt
```

This would get you every column as well as the result of the count.

Comment: Your code seems to be working the best, however the only issue is that there are more than three columns within the table, and for me now to list each and every column to be included in the returned value will take a while, however it can be done. so my question now is, is there another way to then return the rest of the columns as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by the number of record for each user, then use window functions instead of aggregation:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t., count(*) OVER (partition by user) as cnt
      FROM mytable t
     ) t
ORDER BY cnt DESC, user;
```

Note that I added `user` to the `order by` so users with the same count will appear together in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an `outer apply` if your version of SQL Server supports it:

```
SELECT [User], [Ref Num], Date, total_record
FROM mytable M
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT count(*) total_record 
  FROM mytable 
  WHERE [user] = M.[user] 
  GROUP BY [user]
) oa
ORDER BY total_record desc, [user]
```

Note that `user` is a reserved keyword in MSSQL and you need to enclose it in either brackets `[user]` or double-quotes `"user"`.

This would produce an output like:

```
user    Ref Num Date    total_record
1       a   2015-03-17  3
1       b   2015-03-17  3
1       f   2015-03-17  3
4       e   2015-03-17  2
4       e   2015-03-17  2
2       c   2015-03-17  1
3       d   2015-03-17  1
```

Note that the answers using the `count(*) OVER (partition by [user])` construct are more efficient though.

Comment: This not working correctly and `GROUP BY` should be after `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @StanislovasKalašnikovas That's what happens when posting too fast... error fixed now.

Comment: This is also working, however the only issue I have is that the table contains more than three columns and all columns must be returned, as soon as I select * from mytable the query no longer appears to be working. I could take the long way and add each and every column in the table but not the most practical idea.

Comment: @ChantelleBrink The query should work just fine with the `select * from mytable m` see this example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/735005/1

Comment: Thanks, Yes did add that and it also works perfectly. Thanks a mill

Answer (score 0):

Most simple way would be to use window fuction.

```
SELECT table.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY user)
FROM nameoftable table -- this is an alias
ORDER BY user, ref_num
```

This also seem to fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

This is the old way of doing it. Where possible you should use `OVER` but as other people have answered with that I thought I'd throw this one into the mix.

```
SELECT
     T.[User]
    ,T.[Ref Num]
    ,T.[Date]
    ,(SELECT count(*) from [myTable] T2 where T2.[User] = T.[USER]) as [Count]
FROM [mytable] T
ORDER BY [Count] DESC
```